# Problem into find and replace text into a string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm cleaning my product database and I need to substrate text between a "#" and the space after this character to show an example:

ALMINE #6186 3 WAY EM/BRD  --> I need to move the # 6186 at the end of the string.

JOY #197 BD LG GLOW RED --> Here I need to do the same.

Then I need to create a formula to subtract that one an put it at the end I was thinking into look for the space after the # but i can't.

Ill appreciate if you could help me with this.

Ty,

I subtract the character from #-1 to start then in that way I will have the title but ill need to create another formula to extract from the # to the space after the # space because the ID's length change.

Comment: Is there only one # in the string? If not, do you want to always refer to the first?

Comment: Yes sr is just one "#" in the string

Comment: Can you accurately show the result for `ALMINE #6186 3 WAY EM/BRD` (what about the spaces around the string and the space before the string when it's copied to the end)?

Comment: Sure what I'm doing with every item is this:

Almine #4231 Sm Puff Ribon  apply this function =LEFT(C2,FIND("#",C2)-1)

And the result is this :

Almine

But I need to concatenate the other part after the #THEID and put that ID at the end of the string

Comment: So show us the result for `ALMINE #6186 3 WAY EM/BRD`.

Comment: The following is searching for `" #"` (note the leading space): `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,FIND(" #",A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" #",A1)+1)-FIND(" #",A1)),"",1)&MID(A1,FIND(" #",A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" #",A1)+1)-FIND(" #",A1))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the steps in the following image and the corresponding formulas below:

[image]

and in one formula is:

```
=REPLACE(A2,FIND("#",A2),FIND(" ",A2,B2)-FIND("#",A2),"") & " "  &  MID(A2,FIND("#",A2),FIND(" ",A2,B2)-FIND("#",A2))
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yossi THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! you save my life :) !

Comment: magnificent! I was glad to help.
Please vote the answer so others can enjoy it too.

Answer (score 0):

Under Office 365 (there is no tag excel version constraint in the question) you can play with `TEXTBEFORE` and `TEXTAFTER` functions to the get the expected result. Put in `B1` the following formula:

```
=LET(text, A1:A2, prefix, TEXTBEFORE(text," "), suffix, TEXTAFTER(text," "), 
  number, TEXTBEFORE(suffix," "), prefix & TEXTAFTER(suffix, number) &" "& number)
```

**Notes**:

1. This approach doesn't require helper columns
2. It works for a single cell, but also for the Array version, there is no need to drag down the formula. It works for an entire range of data all at once.
3. `LET` is used for the reusability of the calculations.

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

If you enter an

Comment: Hi David Thank you I'll try this one too thank you so much!!!!